# Error compiling Arduino

Tags: arduino

I've just installed the last version of Arduino 1.6.7 plug my Arduino SmartEverything (http://www.smarteverything.it/) to OS X 10.11.2, try to compile this project: https://github.com/nicolsc/sigfox-weather-station/blob/master/sigfox_smart_weather.ino
But i got this error

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware" -hardware "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr" -tools "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -built-in-libraries "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries" -libraries "/Users/nunito/Documents/Arduino/libraries" -fqbn=AMEL:samd:AMEL_SmartEverything_native -vid-pid=0X2341_0XE002 -ide-version=10607 -build-path "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp" -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/arduino_50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431/sketch_jan21c.ino"
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware" -hardware "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr" -tools "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -built-in-libraries "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries" -libraries "/Users/nunito/Documents/Arduino/libraries" -fqbn=AMEL:samd:AMEL_SmartEverything_native -vid-pid=0X2341_0XE002 -ide-version=10607 -build-path "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp" -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/arduino_50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431/sketch_jan21c.ino"
Build options changed, rebuilding all
""   -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_SAMD_SMARTEVERYTHING -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD  -D__SAMD21J18A__        "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/variants/AMEL_SmartEverything" "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/sketch/sketch_jan21c.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
""   -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_SAMD_SMARTEVERYTHING -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD  -D__SAMD21J18A__        "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/variants/AMEL_SmartEverything" "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/sketch/sketch_jan21c.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
""   -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_SAMD_SMARTEVERYTHING -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD  -D__SAMD21J18A__        "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/variants/AMEL_SmartEverything" "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/sketch/sketch_jan21c.ino.cpp" -o "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
exec: "-w": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling.
```

[image]

Comment: [Please avoid posting duplicate questions on multiple SE sites](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19817/error-compiling-arduino)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install **Arduino SAMD Boards (32-bits ARM Cortex-M0+)** board (using "Tools" -> "Board" -> "Boards Manager" menu. Just search for "samd" in the search bar, choose the latest version and install)